# DockerDesktop doesn't run on Hyper-V enabled server machine

Tags: docker, devops, docker-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I would like to build ABP project and docker image on Windows Server 10.0.17763.168.

I have attached the issue.

I have enabled Hyper-V feature on Physical machine.

Thank you for taking the time to consider my problem, all DevOps Engineers.

[DockerVM doesn't run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on31P.png)

Comment: do you have wsl installed on VPS?

Comment: if you'd like to use docker, I recommend you to use ubuntu

Comment: as I look your OS is windows server 2019. and I am confusing if you are concerning at VPS.

Comment: @xuxianjin yes, it's using windows server 2019 and you are right.
It's not VPS, but physical machine. Do you have any idea with Windows 2019 and Docker?
P.S. will change the question content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me tell you my past experience. I encountered the similar case in the past, I downloaded Ubuntu iso image and used it to create a new virtual machine (VM) running Ubuntu. The process for creating a new VM will depend on the virtualization software you are using on your OS. Some popular virtualization software for Windows Server 2019 include Hyper-V, VMware, and VirtualBox. And you can install Docker there.

And I recommend you use docker toolbox.

https://docs.bitnami.com/containers/how-to/install-docker-in-windows/

As you can follow this link, it would be a better approach for your case.

Hope my hints would be helpful for you.

Comment: Great working. Thanks, @xuxianjin.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed docker desktop using below link:
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/
I didn't enabled anything. It worked for me.
If WSL 2 available, then it is easy to implement the docker. If not, then use Hyper-V as backend, but make sure the Virtualation in Task-Manager is enabled.
If WSL 2 is not available.. the link is having the steps for WSL2. follow those steps.

Comment: I have tried 'wsl --install' command, but doesn't work because of old version of windows server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).